# CodeBuild success but CodeDeploy fails

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

Codebuild successfully completes but CodeDeploy fails. Checking the error message states "The action failed because either the artifact or the Amazon S3 bucket could not be found." After checking the codepipeline bucket I see the input artifact there but not the output artifact one. This the code that I am using for the buildspec.yml:

```html
version: 0.2
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
    - echo "Entered the pre-build phase"
  build:
    commands:
    - echo "Entered build phase"
    - mvn package
    - ls
    - (cd target && ls)
    - (cd target/ROOT && ls)
    
  post_build:
    commands:
    - echo "Entered the post-build phase"
    artifacts:
      files:
        - '**/*'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct the artifacts indentation as follows:

```
version: 0.2
phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
    - echo "Entered the pre-build phase"
  build:
    commands:
    - echo "Entered build phase"
    - mvn package
    - ls
    - (cd target && ls)
    - (cd target/ROOT && ls)

  post_build:
    commands:
    - echo "Entered the post-build phase"
artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
```